# WebURK without any kind of subdirectories

Tags: web, url, directory, host, directory-structure

It is my first time seeing something like this.

Does anyone know, what the name/kind/type of the website is that does not have any kind of subdirectories on the web-URL page, and it always just stays as a plain domain name, and how it was made, and how it can be avoided since I need to send an API call to one of those subdirectories?

Example:
I have a website let's call it `example.net`. It has UI page and it has a home page, which should look like this in a browser: `example.net/home`, or it has a /shipment option inside of the UI page. So the URL should look like this:
`example.net/shipment` and it has one more subdirectory inside for example `/report`, and if I select it, it should look like this: `example.net/shipment/report` (something like this).

And open up that subdirectory, but again web-URL link on a website continues to stay just as a `example.net` all the time.

And for some reason whatever subdirectory I would go on a website, Web-browser URL will remain as a hello-world.net all the time without any kind of changes subdirectories on a web-browser URL.

It is an internal website, so I can not post examples of it from work here.

Does anyone knows, what the name of that kind of set?
How it can be avoided? Since I need to send an API request to one of the subdirectories?

I am not a developer, and I am new to IT, so I am not really sure, what the name of this, and how does it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on `example.net/shipment` and you want to link to a subdirectory, the link needs to include that subdirectory.  You have two possibilities:

- Root relative links: `<a href=/shipment/report>`
- Absolute links: `<a href=https://example.com/shipment/report>`

If you shipment directory has a trailing slash (`example.net/shipment/`), you a third possibility.  (Note this **only** works with a shipment URL that is *different* than what you specified in your question.)

- Document relative links: `<href=report>`

There is no name for websites that don't have subdirectories that I know of.  Websites are often set up like this to make the URLs easy to type and remember which helps with SEO.